# Tools for BlackBerry dev

Tags: java, blackberry

I was wondering what are the best tools for BlackBerry dev?

What if there are any plugins for Elcispe. I know the apps are built in Java so I was wondering is there any other lite wieght or heigh IDE's are if there is a GUI program for it.

Answer (score 4):

[RIM has a list of tools you can use](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/devtools.jsp) (e.g. emulators, SDK, etc.). There is [an Eclipse plugin](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp) that RIM distributes and maintains as well. The only IDE that they seem to formally support today is Eclipse, so I'd recommend you use that (though you could use anything you'd like, it'd just be more difficult).